# JavaScript if statement with filter will not work

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, filter

I cannot figure out why I always get the value that I pass into the array and the if statement is not working?

The expected output is "Orange", however I need to pass two string variables into the function and have an if statement to return true or false. No matter what I put in for a test to pass into elementOne and check against elementTwo, I get the value of elementOne, I cannot make the output = false.

This code must not change from the below array and function calls.

```js
var fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"];
var elementTwo = "Apple"
function favoriteFruit(elementOne, elementTwo) {
  if (elementOne === elementTwo)
  return true;
  else
  return false;
}



const result = fruit.filter((elem) => {
  return favoriteFruit("Apple", elementTwo);
});
console.log (result)
```

Comment: Your code is working as it should. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: The code posted works. What is the problem?

Comment: Terribly sorry the expected output is "Orange", however i need to pass two string variables into the function and have an if statement to return true or false.  No matter what I put in for a test to pass into elementOne and check against elementTwo, I get the value of elementOne,  I cannot make the output = false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @binarie ! As listed in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"];

function favoriteFruit(elementOne, elementTwo) {
  return elementOne === elementTwo;
}

const result = fruit.filter((elem) => {
  return favoriteFruit("Orange", elem);
});
```

Outputs: `["Orange"]` in case of `elementOne` is "Orange", and `[]` if `elementOne` is something not from the given array.

If you need to return a boolean, then use this:

```js
...

const result = !!fruit.filter((elem) => {
  return favoriteFruit("Apple", elem);
}).length;
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to check against the given elementTwo, then:

```js
var fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"];

var elementTwo = "Apple";

function favoriteFruit(needle, checkAgainst) {
  return needle === checkAgainst;
}

const result = fruit.filter((elem) => {
  return favoriteFruit(elem, elementTwo);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused as for this example I am required to use an if statement in the function to test against two string variables.  What am I missing?

Comment: You still CAN use `if(elementOne === elementTwo){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }` if you want (need) to. This above is just a shorthand.

Comment: Gotcha, however I am not sure how the shorthand works yet.  I am sorry I am a bit of a novice and am trying to learn. I am sorry and I am trying to write the results to the console.log

Comment: Okay, just keep in mind, that `===` operator returns boolean. Now try to read the code above...

Comment: It reads: if `elementOne === elementTwo`, then return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: I am so sorry, however I still would like to ask another question.  Do I continue to check the value of elementOne by doing a var elementTwo = "(whatever I am checking against?)

Comment: Updated the answer. Is it what you were looking for? @binarie

Comment: So here is what I have, when I check I get all values in the array as a result.  I must be missing something.  I have updated my code above.

Comment: No, not all values: https://jsfiddle.net/9w6p4tuo/

Comment: I think I have got it!  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're just checking `"apple"` and `"apple"`which will always execute to true. You need to replace your `return favoriteFruit("Apple", elementTwo);` with `return favoriteFruit(elem, elementTwo);`. The snippet below works for you.

**Note:** I also added the curly brackets after the if/else statement. Although it isn't necessary (if you didn't have brackets, it would still work), it's still good practice to include them.

**For example,**

```
if (true)
  //action
```

is the same thing as

```
if (true) {
  //action
}
```

**However**

```
if (true) 
  //action1
  //action2
```

is the same thing as

```
if (true) {
  //action1
}
//action2
```

**TL;DR:** Use curly brackets after if/else statements all the time.

**Update:** I just realized you could get rid of the if statement completely. In your if statement, if `elementOne == elementTwo` is true, it returns true. If `elementOne == elementTwo` is false, it returns false. See the pattern?

You could simply return `elementOne == elementTwo` which is the same thing you are doing.

```js
var fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"];
var elementTwo = "Apple"

function favoriteFruit(elementOne, elementTwo) {
  return elementOne == elementTwo
}



const result = fruit.filter((elem) => {
  return favoriteFruit(elem, elementTwo);
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Aha Thank you all for your help!  You have been awesome.

Comment: @binarie did it work for you how you wanted?

Comment: @binarie No problem. Always glad to help. There are 2 answers on this question. Accept whichever one you like better.